# Sed append to end of line directory

Tags: bash, variables, unix, sed, directory

I'm very new to SED and I'm having a hard time trying to append to an end of a directory. What I'm doing involves 2 basic things with sed but for some reason, no changes are made after the script runs. I will show segments of my script

I have a bash script that pulls my home directory from the host and I define the ID variable.

```
USERNAME="test"

#pull the home directory
dir=$(ssh -n -t $SERVERNAME "echo \$HOME";)
```

the above example will store /export/home/ID in the `dir` variable

```
echo $dir | sed 's/\([/export/home]*\).*/\1/' > olddir
```

the sed command above stores /export/home/ in the file `olddir`  (takes off the ending)

```
sed -i 's_/home/$ _\$USERNAME_' olddir
```

i am now trying to change `/export/home/` to `/export/home/test` using the defined variable with the escaped `$`.

after the script runs, it still has `/export/home/` as the entry in the `olddir` file. 
I'm using the `-i` to modify the file and I think I'm using the deliminators correctly? what could I be doing wrong? i even took off the `$` from the USERNAME variable which didn't do anything. I know I'm missing something small but i just can't figure it out. I really appreciate your time to answer my question.

Comment: Why do you need an auxiliary file? from your `dir` variable, you can get what you want in the variable `newdir` as so: `newdir=${dir%/*}/$USERNAME`. Now the reason why it fails is because you're using single quotes: bash forbids expansion of variables within single quotes. Instead: `sed -i 's_/home/$_'"$USERNAME"'_' olddir` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using the provided information and playing around with the code, I found a solution that will work for both /export/home/ID and /home/ID situations.

I used both Xorg and also gniourf_gniourf's suggestions and below is my result.

```
echo $dir | sed 's_\([/export/home\]*\).*_\1_' > olddir
```

The above code is the first part of my solution.
I used what Xorg provided for the above code but it looks like i need those `[]` so i can use the `*\` if i have it as `echo $dir | sed 's_\(/export/home\).*_\1_' > olddir` then the `olddir` file will contain `/export/home/ID/test` after the following sed command is used.

Here is the following sed command that I used:

```
sed -i 's_/home_&/'"$USERNAME"'_' olddir
```

The above code is the second part of my solution. I figured that I really only need to put focus on /home/ since i'm appending after it. I looked at  gniourf_gniourf's comment and used the example where the quotes to isolate `$USERNAME` with `""` that seems to be the way you can tell the script to use $USERNAME as a variable and not just put in the characters `$USERNAME`.

so after the script is run, depending on the host, I either have `export/home/test/` or `/home/test/`  I can now put either of these into a new variable on the script to use to specify the home directory when creating ID's on remote hosts!

```
newdir="$(cat olddir)"
```

Thank you all so much for your help. I wouldn't have been able to figure this out with out your help.

Update: it turns out that the traling / at the end of directory is problem so i found a much easier way to replace the ID in the home directory

`newdir="${dir/ID/${USERNAME}}"`

i used these if statments for both home directory situations

`if [[ $dir == "/home/dhabinsk" ]]; then
        newdir="${dir/dhabinsk/${USERNAME}}"
    fi

```
if [[ $dir == "/export/home/dhabinsk" ]]; then
    newdir="${dir/dhabinsk/${USERNAME}}"
fi`
```

cheers

Comment: Sorry for garbage in my previous comment, but I cannto edit it any more (after 5 minutes).  This solution may work for your special case, but is generally wrong. Your first command searches not for an expression "/export/home/", but for a bunch of letters in any particular order. Check that it would match "/home/em/" for example, not discarding the last part.

Answer (score 0):

I think your command line can be modified then redirect output to olddir as follows:

```
echo $dir | sed 's#\(/export/home\).*#\1#' > olddir
```

to add the USERNAME VARIABLE

```
sed -i "s#/export/home#&/$USERNAME#" olddir
```

Comment: Hello Xorg. I tried what you provided and I'm making progress thanks to your help. at this point, after i have used your `sed -i 's_/export/home_&/$USERNAME_' olddir` but now it is putting `$USERNAME` not the variable value, but the literal characters $USERNAME in the field after the /home/ directory. `/export/home/$USERNAME` I even tried escaping the `$` in USERNAME which didn't make a difference and I used your alternate command for redirecting output with the same result. I did find a solution after playing around though. I"ll post it.

Comment: instead of using 's_/export/home_&/$USERNAME_' use  "s_/export/home_&/$USERNAME_" with double qoutes this will enable bash to substitute your script variable into sed.